# Why does shallow rendering component with mock json seem to cause declaration exception?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, declaration, enzyme

When I run the test script for my **StreamItem.js** react component I receive the following command line error:

```
StreamItem › encountered a declaration exception

TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile_image_url' of undefined

  at StreamItem.tweetOrRetweetProfileImageSetter.tweet [as tweetOrRetweetProfileImageSetter] (src/components/StreamItem.js:7:135)
  at _react2.default.createElement.props.streamItemsFromParent.map.tweet (src/components/StreamItem.js:16:181)
      at Buffer.map (<anonymous>)
  at StreamItem.render (src/components/StreamItem.js:15:42)
  at ReactShallowRenderer._mountClassComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:187:37)
  at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:135:14)
  at node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:287:35
  at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/build/Utils.js:94:16)
  at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:286:68)
  at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:119:22)
  at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/build/shallow.js:19:10)
  at Suite.Object.<anonymous>.describe (src/components/StreamItem.test.js:12:42)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/StreamItem.test.js:9:1)
      at <anonymous>
```

Perhaps this error is due to limitations surrounding enzyme's shallow rendering feature?  Especially when it comes to parsing mock data...?  Below I have provided copies of the component's test, the component itself and a gist link to the mock data parsed as props in the test.

**repo/react-client/src/components/StreamItem.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import StreamItem from './StreamItem';

const fs = require("fs");
const mockData = fs.readFileSync('../express-backend/mock_data/tweet.json');

describe('StreamItem', () => {
  const mockRemove = jest.fn();
  const props = {streamItemsFromParent: mockData}
  const streamItem = shallow(<StreamItem {...props} />);

});
```

**repo/react-client/src/components/StreamItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class StreamItem extends Component {

  tweetOrRetweetProfileImageSetter = tweet => {

    const tweetProfileImage = tweet.hasOwnProperty('retweeted_status') ? tweet.retweeted_status.user.profile_image_url : tweet.user.profile_image_url;
    return tweetProfileImage

  }

  render() {
      return (
        <ul>
          {this.props.streamItemsFromParent.map(tweet =>
            <li key={tweet.id}><img src={this.tweetOrRetweetProfileImageSetter(tweet)} alt='Profile' />{tweet.text}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      )
  }
}


export default StreamItem;
```

**repo/express-backend/mock_data/tweet.json**  (mock json file used for tests) Gist: https://gist.github.com/oliverpople/653f17546845ef1d580e741605e0fc42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't parse the JSON. You should specify encoding in the `readFileSync` function so that it returns a string instead of a buffer and then use `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON:

```
const mockData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../express-backend/mock_data/tweet.json', 'utf8'));
```

Comment: This results in the new error:   

   `StreamItem › encountered a declaration exception`
  `TypeError: this.props.streamItemsFromParent.map is not a function`

Comment: @Oliver Well, the JSON is a single object, not an array of objects, so you can't use `map` on it. Either change your code to render a single tweet, or wrap that mock tweet in an array.